# Should I be installing Nginx from source or PPA?

Tags: nginx

Nginx source seems far different from the Nginx PPA. Mostly the way PHP is configured, and the different sites-available config. Should I be installing the source version, or the Nginx from the PPA?

Comment: I would rather use docker and run nginx on docker. Make it easy to test new versions and upgrade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to your need as per the reason below.

- from PPA. This is a quick and easy way to install NGINX Open Source. The package includes almost all NGINX official modules and is available for most popular operating systems. See Installing a Pre-Built Package for details.
- compiled from the sources. This way is more flexible: you can add particular modules including 3rd party modules or apply latest security patches. See Compiling and Installing From the Sources for details.

I almost always select PPA option as I just need it as is, and I don't have to deal with compilation dependencies or `./configure` command line options :-).

Here is what I did for installing on Ubuntu 14.04

```
$ sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
  >>> add 'deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu/ trusty nginx' to your package source list 
$ wget -q http://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Just replace trusty with with whatever Ubuntu version codename applicable.